# Show that the sequence of $a_n=\frac{1}{ne^{a_{n-1}}}$, with $a_1>0$, is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A Physics student came to me with an exercise they were given in their Analysis course (first year):

**Show that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, where $a_n=\frac{1}{ne^{a_{n-1}}}$, $a_1>0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.**

The way I would do the exercise is by simply noting $0\leq a_n\leq 1/n$ for all $n$, which holds because the $a_n$ are positive and then $e^{a_{n-1}}>1$. Then it is enough to argue that the sequences $\{0\}$ and $\{1/n\}$ converge to the same value so $\{a_n\}$ also converges.

The problem is that the students have not seen this "sandwitch theorem" in their course so they feel they shouldn't use it. The way they have been proving the convergence of sequences is by proving they are monotonous and bounded. The proofs of monotony are usually done by induction by assuming $a_{n}-a_{n-1}>0$ (or $<0$) and showing the same inequality holds for $a_{n+1}-a_n$.

In this case, if to study the monotony one investigates the ratio $a_{n}/a_{{n+1}}$, one reaches

$$
\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{n}e^{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}.
$$

If we assume $a_{n}-a_{n-1}<0$ (decreasing sequence) to carry out the induction proof, then the exponential is smaller than 1 but the factor $(n+1)/n$ is higher than 1, so we cannot conclude directly that the ratio $a_{n}/a_{{n+1}}$ is higher or smaller than one. If instead we assume $a_{n}-a_{n-1}>0$, then $a_{n}/a_{{n+1}}>1$, which means $a_n>a_{n+1}$ so that the $(n+1)$-th case does not hold.

At this stage I am not sure there is an easy way to prove the sequence is decreasing (numerically one can see it is decreasing at least from $n=3$), but perhaps anyone here can come up with an answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily decreasing. Take $a_1 := 10^{-100}$. Then,

$$ a_2^{-1} = 2 \cdot e^{10^{-100}} \approx 2 (1 - 10^{-100}). $$

So, clearly $a_2 \approx 1/2 \gg 10^{-100} = a_1$.

There are conditions under which it is monotone, though. First, let's look at $a_{n+1} - a_n$:

$$ a_{n+1} - a_n = \tfrac1{n+1} e^{-a_n} - a_n < \tfrac1{n+1} - a_n(1 + \tfrac1{n+1}). $$

Hence, a *sufficient* condition for $a_{n+1} - a_n < 0$ is

$$ \tfrac1{n+1} - a_n (1 + \tfrac1{n+1}) \le 0
\iff
a_n \ge \frac{1/(n+1)}{1 + 1/(n+1)} = \frac1{n+2}. $$

We turn to showing this; it must be imposed for $n = 0$. Clearly, $a_{n-1} \ge 1/(n-1)$ for $n \ge 2$. Hence, for $n \ge 2$,

$$ a_n = \frac1{ne^{a_{n-1}}} \ge \frac1{ne^{1/(n-1)}} \approx \frac1{n(1+1/(n-1))} = \frac1{n + 1 + 1/(n-1)} \ge \frac1{n+2}. $$

The approximation $e^{1/(n-1)} \approx 1 + 1/(n-1)$ needs to be made rigorous. More precisely,

$$ e^{1/(n-1)} \le 1 + 2/n \implies a_n \ge 1/(n+2). $$

This exponential inequality holds for $n \ge 3$. Hence,

$$ a_3 > a_4 > a_5 > \cdots. $$

You can play around with initial conditions and inequalities to handle the early cases to your heart's content. A sufficient condition is

$$ a_0 \le \tfrac12, \quad a_1 \le \tfrac13 \quad\text{and}\quad a_2 \le \tfrac14. $$

Generally, it won't be true that $a_2 > a_3$, though.

---

Do note, though, that these last conditions are not *necessary*. I only found *sufficient* conditions for monotonicity. These are satisfied for $n \ge 3$, so that's not a problem, but you could surely come up with some sequence which is monotonic and doesn't satisfy my conditions for the small-$n$ case.

Your motivation was convergence, though, so I was much less interested in small $n$.

Comment: Yes, that is true but with your value of $a_1$, $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for $n>4$, so the sequence is decreasing from that point on. That makes me think one should be able to carry out an induction proof with a base case at $n=n_0$ with $n_0$ some positive integer.

Comment: @NéstorGonzálezGracia Indeed. I just added that first part of the answer whilst showing the large-$n$ inequality. I showed it for $n \ge 3$, as $n \in \{1,2\}$ is more fiddly

Comment: Plus, it really just isn't true for small $n$. Even $a_0 = 0.2$ gives $a_1 \approx 0.82$, $a_2 \approx 0.22$ and $a_3 \approx 0.26 > 0.22 \approx a_2$

Comment: Sorry, my first comment referred only to the first version of your answer. Now you added full details I understand how the proof is done, so thank you! I see also that the exponential inequality necessary for the sufficient condition to hold, $e^{1/(n-1)}\leq1+2/n$, is proven by induction fairly easly, so a first-year student should be able to follow your proof.

Comment: @NéstorGonzálezGracia No apology necessary! I should've been clearer in my phrasing that I added the $n \ge 3$ part *after*. It's a bit weird to have to show a *lower* bound on $a_n$ in order to show that $a_n$ is *decreasing*! Nice question, I like it! I answer very few questions on SE these days, only the really interesting ones :)